# Implementing Integer Division in hardware

Tags: hardware, alu

I am trying to figure out how to create an efficient way to divide 5 bit numbers in hardware (using registers, Shift Registers, Comparators, Muxes, basic logic
gates, bit shifters, bit extenders, and Subtractors).

I know i can just iteratively subtract the divisor from the dividend until the result is less than the dividend but that takes an unknown number of clock ticks. I am looking for a way to have the entire division done in 6 clock ticks (assuming the above circuits all do their job on a single tick).

I am having trouble getting started because the only methods i come up with use a looping method.

Any advice on how to approach this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 5 bit numbers? A lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice approach is to start with the dividend in a register whose width equals the combined widths of the divisor and intended quotient.  Then repeatedly compare the upper portion of that register against the divisor.  If it's greater than or equal, subtract the divisor and shift the register left, putting a "1" in the LSB.  If it's less, shift left, putting a "0" in the LSB.  Iterate that once for each bit of the quotient.  The lower part of the dividend register will be left holding the quotient, while the upper part will be left holding the remainder.

Depending upon how exactly you do things, it may be necessary to handle the first or last iteration specially, but the above approach is pretty straightforward.

Comment: thanks for the reply! To elaborate, lets say my dividend is 10101 and divisor is 00110, and we want the quotient and remainder to always be five bits. We start out with the dividend in the leftmost or right most portion of a shift register? I assume you want it to be leftmost so the MSB of the shift register is the MSB of the dividen. So our shift register is 1010100000 (the left most 5 bits is the dividend and rightmost is the divisor). Then compare the divisor to the upper part (10101) of the register. If its greater or equal subtract the divisor (00110) from ONLY the upper part (10101).

Comment: (continued) after you subtract the divisor from only the upper part we then move the result of the subtraction back into the upper part of the register (so it would now be 01111) back into the shift registers upper half and then left shift a 1 into the register so the register now looks like 111100001. Then continue until we have shifted 5 times? after all that is through the lower part has the quotient and upper part has the remainder? I feel like those should be switched (lower part has remainder and upper part has quotient).

Comment: @user8363: If the value to be used as the dividend is shorter than the aforementioned register, it should be left padded with zeroes.  The initial value of the shift register should be 00000 10101, so 00000 is the value to be compared against the divisor (it's less).  Then 00001, 00010, and 000101.  Finally, 01010 will be bigger than the divisor, so subtract and yield 00100.  Shift that left (01001) and compare again.  Still greater, so subtract (yielding 00011).  As noted, first and last iteration may need tweaking, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @user8363: The bottom part of the dividend register is where the results of the comparison are getting placed, while the upper part is where the residue from the lower bits of the dividend will eventually end up.

Comment: So i am following up until you get a number greater than the divisor, then you subtract our the divisor from that number and shift that number left (with a 1 not a zero), where do you store that number? Since you aren't shifting the register anymore (you are shifting the result from subtraction).

Comment: It's simplest conceptually to think in terms of subtracting the divisor from the upper part of the dividend and storing the result to the same register, then shifting the entire dividend register left, with a "1" being shifted into the bottom place.  In practice, the subtract and shift operations can be combined.

Comment: so do we clear the register when we store the result from subtraction? or do we only store the result in one half of the register?

Comment: @user8363: Think of it as subtracting a dividend-sized value which is right-padded with zeroes from the dividend.  Subtracting zeroes from the lower bits will leave them unaffected.

Comment: ahh so we subtract the divisor from the entire dividend register but the divisor is padded on right with 5 zeros so it only effects the upper half. Then we left shift a 1 in and continue the process. We stop after 5 shifts?

Comment: i just ran through this on paper and the quotient was correct until we shifted in the last 1, but shifting in the last 1 made the remainder correct. So you are right, maybe the last iteration needs to only shift a 1 into the lower half and not change the upper half. How would i implement a (if this is the last shift) logic in circuitry though?

Comment: Consider various places you could add an extra bit to the divisor register, or what happens if you shift before the compare versus after, etc.  There are a few ways things can be made to work.